# Backbone.js Doubt

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following Parent Object:

```
Context = {
   ContextModel: Backbone.Model.extend({
      //model Code
   }),
   ContextList:Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model : Context.ContextModel
      // collection Code
   }),
   Contexts: new Context.ContextList,
   ContextView: Backbone.View.extend({
      // view Code
   }) 
}
```

In the above code,`model : Context.ContextModel` throws an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: Context is not defined`. I have defined the Context Object but somehow it does not see it. Could someone please help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look through the eyes of the JavaScript interpreter. You have a statement, `Context = { ... }`. In order to execute that statement, it has to first construct the `{ ... }` so it can assign it to `Context`. In order to construct the `{ ... }`, it needs to evaluate `new Context.ContextList`. Unfortunately, it's still constructing the `{ ... }` part, and has not assigned anything to `Context` yet. Thus, `Context` is undefined when you attempt to create a new instance of `Context.ContextList`. You have the same problem trying to access `Context.ContextModel` when creating `Context.ContextList`. Try this:

```
Context = {
   ContextModel: Backbone.Model.extend({
      //model Code
   }),
   ContextView: Backbone.View.extend({
      // view Code
   }) 
}
Context.ContextList=Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Context.ContextModel
    // collection Code
});
Context.Contexts=new Context.ContextList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var Context = {};
Context.ContextModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      //model Code
});
Context.ContextList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model : Context.ContextModel
   // collection Code
});
Context.Contexts = new Context.ContextList;
Context.ContextView = Backbone.View.extend({
   // view Code
});
```

Problem solved.

The issue is that your doing logic in your assignment of the Object literal. The `Context` variable only exists after the assignment is finished, which is finished after the object literal is constructed.

To avoid this don't do logical execution in a object literal, it should be a static collection of values and methods.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer writing it this way

```
var ContextModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      //model Code
   })
var ContextList = ContextModel({
      model : contextModel
      // collection Code
   })
var Context = {
   ContextModel: ContextModel,
   ContextList: ContextList,
   Contexts: new ContextList,
   ContextView: Backbone.View.extend({
      // view Code
   }) 
}
```